# Is there a way to find location names in block of text

Tags: java, algorithm, parsing, geolocation, location

Is there a way to parse text to find location names in a piece of text?

For example:

> EU leaders holding late-night talks in Brussels have agreed to relocate tens of thousands of migrants who have arrived in Italy and Greece.

In the above text there are three locations, `Italy`, `Greece`, and `Brussels`. Is there an API service that can take a piece of text and provide the list of locations found in the text? Or even better, provide LAT/LONG of the found locations.

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is a `Text Mining` issue for which a lot of tools are available. More specifically, your problem is called `Named Entity Recognition (NER)`, which is a sub-field of text mining.

I would suggest using this information and google around a bit, because there is no easy answer/go-to to solve your issue.
The only alternative is to make (or ideally download) a list containing all locations in the world, though that's of course **very** inefficient.

Here is an API which should be able to get you going, although you might need to play around with the library for a while I suppose.

> http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/